# How to add <br> in tooltip in <td>

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
<tr>
<td>HOVER ME< i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="1st line of text <br> 2nd line of text"></i></td>
</tr>
```

No matter what i do it doesn't comes on next line.i have also tried with Environment.Newline ,,\n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `&#013;` and combine it with `white-space: pre-line;` in CSS.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Easy and clever! Cool! I did not know it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: we learn something new every day...